# Use of unresolved identifier 'cell' in xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my match app Xcode project I have an error stating:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'.

**My Code:**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var model = CardModel()
    var cardArray:[Card] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //call the getCards method of the card model
        cardArray = model.getCards()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    //mark: -UICollectionView Protocol Methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return cardArray.count
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //get a cardCollectionViewcell object
        let cell =
            collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

        //get card that
        let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.setCard(card)

        return
  }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        _ = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!CardCollectionViewCell

        //flip the card
        cell.flip() <--------- THIS IS THE ERROR
```

Once the error is fixed I am supposed to be able run a match app example on the fake iPhone. It would allow me to flip the cards on a click.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set reusable identifier

[image: Storyboard set cell identifier]

I hope this will be resolve your issue.

To access that cell method you have to declare variable 
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!CardCollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are misusing `collectionView:willDisplay:forItemAt`. Move everything into `collectionView:cellForItemAt`, replace `return` with `return cell` and delete `willDisplay:`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

    //get card that
    let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCard(card)
    return cell
}
```

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { ... }
```

The error is pretty clear: You never declared `cell` is the scope of `didSelectItemAt`. Change

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell
```

Comment: I u[dated the answer.

Comment: Of course you have to delete the method `cellForItemAt` at the beginning of the class. Please don't become a *copier&paster*. Learn the stuff.

Comment: Please ask a new question and accept this one if it helped.